# Eclipse New Project Error: OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: force.com, eclipse, ide

I am trying to create a new Force.com Project and I am getting:

> OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space error.

I lowered the amount of metadata components I am bringing over to only be the 6 Apex Triggers I am trying to delete and I updated the .ini file to increase the XXMaxPermSize to 1024m and I am still getting the error. I also made sure that I had the most up to date version of the IDE. I am not sure what to do here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have also faced this issue many time. You can do one thing .Once you get this error now change radio button to None and click save. It will fetch all your selected data and you can continue your work.

[image]

You don't need to lower any metadata it will work in most case. If this doesn't work for you then initially click on None and create a empty project. Now select Apex class, Trigger and all folder one by one and refresh them. It will fetch all your metadata.

Comment: So I created the empty project and then I clicked on triggers and clicked Force.com and then Refresh from Server but nothing happened. Am I missing something?

Comment: @cmmoutes13 did you get any error? or in bottom right any green counter is running?

Comment: No nothing. A loading window came up for a second, but I couldn't see what it said and then it went away and then nothing

Comment: @cmmoutes13 try to click on parent `src` folder.

Comment: Tushar, I deleted the project and started fresh and tried your first recommendation again and it worked. Thanks so much for the help!